# How to dismiss DetailView without closing the whole window in SwiftUI MacOS app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationview

Here is an example of two SwiftUI views with unexpected behavior of closing the window instead of dismissing DetailView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Go to detail view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
}
```

[Ans here is the video showing this behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M53jE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you could use NavigationSplitView also to let you know NavigationView now deprecated

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDetailViewPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Button("Go to detail view") {
                isDetailViewPresented = true
            }
        } detail: {
            if  isDetailViewPresented {
                DetailView(isPresented: $isDetailViewPresented)
            }
        }
    }
}
    


struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Detail View")
                Button(action: { isPresented.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
    }
}
```